# Showing $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has directional derivatives in every direction at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=\{\sin\left(\frac{y^2}{x}\right)\cdot\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ if $x\neq0$

$f(0,y)=0$

I assume I start off with something along the lines of $D_u(0,0)=\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0,0)}{t}$, where $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

And $f(0,0)=0$, so essentially $D_u(0,0)=\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(tu)}{t}$.

The answer's probably looking me right in the face, but I can't seem to get farther than this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to get you started: Let $u=(1,1).$ Then

$$\frac{f(tu)}{t} = \frac{\sin (t)\cdot \sqrt 2 |t|}{t}.$$